# How do I update my Sql database using Java

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if(action.equals("Reset")){
        title.setSelectedIndex(0);
        forename.setText(null);
        surname.setText(null);
        age.setText(null);
        contactNo.setText(null);
        houseNo.setText(null);
        streetName.setText(null);
        districtName.setText(null);
        cityName.setText(null);
        postcode.setText(null);
        healthPlan.setSelectedIndex(0);
        treatment.setSelectedIndex(0);  

    }
```

How do I update my sql database with data from the textfield when I click the "Submit" button. I have written this code so far but nothing seems to be happening when I click submit, but the reset button works when it is clicked.

```
    if(action.equals("Submit")){
        Connection con = null; 
        String db="jdbc:mysql://stusql.dcs.shef.ac.uk/team009?user=team009&password=********";

        try { 

           con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
           Statement bil = con.createStatement();

           bil.execute("INSERT INTO Patient (ForeName, SurName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, HouseNumber, PostCode) " + 
            "VALUES (forename.getText(),surname.getText,age.getText,contactNo.getText(),houseNo.getText(),postcode.getText())");

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!");

        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
         if (con != null)
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Please any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your current "query" should throw an exception - define *"but nothing seems to be happening when I click submit"*

Comment: when I click submit the form remains the same nothing changes and the database isn't updated.

Comment: Assuming that no exception is printed to the console and that the `"Inserted Successfully!"` is not displayed, you `actionCommand` could be wrong.  Start by adding some debugging statements to track the flow through your code (printing the `actionCommand` to start with and some message about where you are in the code), if that doesn't seem to help, add break points and begin debugging your code...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you current query `String`

```
"INSERT INTO Patient (ForeName, SurName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, HouseNumber, PostCode) " + 
        "VALUES (forename.getText(),surname.getText,age.getText,contactNo.getText(),houseNo.getText(),postcode.getText())"
```

Is literally asking the database to insert the text you have supplied and NOT the text from text fields, in fact, the database should pretty much have a fit over this and throw back an `Exception`.  At best, it's trying to find table/column values matching things like `surname.getText` at worst it's looking for functions called `forename.getText()`

Start by taking a look at:

- [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)
- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

For example...

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(null)) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Patient (ForeName, SurName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, HouseNumber, PostCode) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
        stmt.setString(1, forename.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, surname.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, age.getText());
        stmt.setString(4, contactNo.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, houseNo.getText());
        stmt.setString(6, postcode.getText());
        // In case you care, you can get the number of rows that were updated...
        int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

And you might find [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) useful...

Comment: This triggers the message but the database isn't updated

Comment: Then you probably have autocommit turned off.  Try adding `con.commit()` after the `executeUpdate` statement

Answer (score 0):

You were not sending the values of `forename`, `surname` etc. but instead sending the string
for calling these values in java. You are needed to that part of your code with this : -

```
bil.execute("INSERT INTO Patient (ForeName, SurName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, HouseNumber, PostCode) VALUES ("'
    + forename.getText() + "', '"
    + surname.getText() + "', '"
    + age.getText() + "', '"
    + contactNo.getText() + "', '"
    + houseNo.getText() + "', '"
    + postcode.getText() + "')");
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I just wanted to say the last line + postcode.getText())");xt,contactNo.getText(),houseNo.getText(),postcode.getText())"); is giving me an error

Comment: I am sorry. I mistakenly didn't marked that in hurry.

Comment: after trying this answer i am getting a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'alex' in 'field list',when i run the code and input alex in the name textfield

Comment: To debug your code write following line just before execution and check the output : 
`System.out.println("INSERT INTO Patient (ForeName, SurName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, HouseNumber, PostCode) VALUES ("
    + forename.getText() + ", "
    + surname.getText() + ", "
    + age.getText() + ", "
    + contactNo.getText() + ", "
    + houseNo.getText() + ", "
    + postcode.getText() + ")")`

Comment: And I wanna remark that if MadProgrammer's answer is working than this will also work. You might be doing some other mistake.

Comment: I have edited answer, and added single quotes. (because `prepareStatement` adds them itself in query). So now it will definitely work of other answer is working.

Comment: MadProgrammers answer triggers the successful message but it doesnt update the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66078/discussion-between-afzalex-and-thebean).